# Azure Devops Pipelines Nuget restore failed with packages not used in project

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

The steps for Nuget restore from pipeline is like below

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
```

nuget restore step was failed with error

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Failed to download package 'Portable.BouncyCastle.1.8.5' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/portable.bouncycastle/1.8.5/portable.bouncycastle.1.8.5.nupkg'.
```

portable.bouncycastle is not used anywhere in the project So don't know how this error comes. Is it pipeline configuration / something else?

Comment: I don't think this package is used by pipeline configuration. Have you tried to set [System.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) to `true` to check the detailed debug log?

Comment: Devops itself fixed this issue. When i run the release pipeline now its working without any issues. Looks like some issues internal to devops and which is sorted automatically